# CMake keeps taking Python from cygwin python, how to take from windows installed Python

Tags: python, windows, cmake, cygwin

I have CMake script which looks like this:

```
find_program(PYTHON_COMMAND NAMES python3 python)
```

The problem is that it detects the python which installed in the Cygwin installation.
The output is always:

```
-- PYTHON_PATH:C:/cygwin64/bin/python3
```

I want it to take from:

```
c:\Python36-64\python
```

In the windows PATH variable, the Cygwin bin is last in the path and the windows installation is first
but yet it only detected the Cygwin python,
how to change it?

Comment: have you tried to NOT use the cygwin `Cmake` or to NOT put the Cygwin directories in the `PATH` ?

Comment: There is [FindPython3](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/FindPython3.html). Please try `find_package (Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter)` which will define `Python3_EXECUTABLE`. Not sure if that will work for your setup, but it's worth a try.

Comment: You could add every `NO_*_PATH` option except for `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html Not sure this will work though. You could later narrow it down to the relevant option(s), if it works...